# two html canvases ontop of each other, one game layer and one gui layer. Good/bad?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics, rendering

Is creating graphics with two HTML canvases in layer a good idea performance wise? One layer for the game and one for the gui.

Is this type of graphics normal?

Thanks.

Comment: Quick answer: it depends on your project, but yes.

Comment: @FerryKranenburg Should i put two html canvases exactly on top of each other or is there some better way like using the same element but using multiple contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put them exacltly on top of each other. The gui canvas could be given a lower refresh rate (fps) and the game canvas a very high refresh rate. Also for 'hidden' and/or 'not visible' canvas elements, it is a good idea to put them on a hidden canvas, a canvas to temporary store those elements when you do not need to render them every frame.

But this requires moving elements from one canvas to another. You would be best of using a HTML canvas framework, like for example [createjs](http://createjs.com/).